# Use of pywin32 to open Word doc and read existing textbox variable

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

I am trying to use pywin32 to open a Word document and copy the values from some text boxes and just print them out. The code and error are below. Any help greatly appreciated. I have looked far and long with no answers to this probably simple question.

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = 0
doc = word.Documents.Open('C:/testdoc.docm')
question2 = ActiveDocument.Variables("txtQuestion02").Value

print question2
```

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rjudge/SkyDrive/Programming/SAP Assignment grading/Grade MS Word - Doc version.py", line 18, in 
    question2 = ActiveDocument.Variables("txtQuestion02").Value
NameError: name 'ActiveDocument' is not defined

Most recent errors after Bernie's suggestion:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Robert/SkyDrive/Programming/SAP Assignment grading/Grade MS Word - Doc version.py", line 18, in 
    question2 = word.ActiveDocument.Variables("txtQuestion02").Value

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 463, in **getattr**
    return self.*ApplyTypes*(*args)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 456, in *ApplyTypes*
    self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Word', u'Object has been deleted.', u'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\WDMAIN11.CHM', 25305, -2146822463), None)

Process finished with exit code 1

**Way in which txtQuestion02 is set in Word (VBA code for the textbox):**

`

Private Sub txtQuestion02_Change()

Me.txtAnswer02.Value = Me.txtQuestion02.Value

End Sub
`

The variable does show it has the correct value when I look at local variables and it does immediately change whenever I change what is in the textbox. The txtQuestion02.value does seem to be doing what it is supposed to do. I just can't seem to access using pywin32. Right now I am going down a terrible road of printing out to text where I can manipulate it with python. But that is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveDocument` has not been defined in your code, but it has been defined as an instance of the Document class within the Word application (called `word` in your code sample). Try instead:

```
question2 = word.ActiveDocument.Variables("txtQuestion02").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but that did not fix it. There is a different set of errors:

Comment: You're most welcome. Please edit your question to show how you are setting the "txtQuestion02" variable in the macro-enabled document.